# Dynamic method creation with javascript/nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, method-invocation

I'm trying to create a nodejs module that will have an api like this

```
**program.js**

var module = require('module');
var products = module('car', 'pc'); // convert string arguments to methods

// now use them 
products.car.find('BMW', function(err, results){
  // results
})

products.pc.find('HP', function(err, results){
  // results
})
```

>

```
**module.js**

function module(methods){
  // convert string arguments into methods attach to this function
  // and return
}

module.find = function(query){
  // return results
};

module.exports = module;
```

I know this is possible because this [module](https://github.com/mafintosh/mongojs) is doing the exact same thing. 
I have tried to study the source but there is just to much going so was not able to determine how its doing this.

Comment: Can you be more explicit about what you're trying to do in English? Please don't show code that doesn't work and then expect us to figure out what it should be doing.

Comment: `var result = {}; [].forEach.call(arguments, function(arg){ result.arg = new Finder()}); return result` is that what you find?

Comment: What is it you are having problem understanding? I think I explained what the module's api/usage should look like. I'm just having problems  how to implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this perhaps? Kinda hard to answer without additionnal details:

```
function Collection(type) {
    this.type = type;
}

Collection.prototype = {
    constructor: Collection,
    find: function (item, callback) {
        //code to find
    }
};

function collectionFactory() {
    var collections = {},
        i = 0,
        len = arguments.length,
        type;

    for (; i < len; i++) {
        collections[type = arguments[i]] = new Collection(type);
    }

    return collections;

}

module.exports = collectionFactory;
```

Comment: I was in the middle of writing an answer with this exact same implementation then this popped up. +1 for this way of doing it

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what do you want to do but remember you can have dynamic property name of an object using [] notation like ...

```
var MyModule = function(param1, param2) {
  this.funcTemplate = function() {
    console.log('Hi ');
  };

  this[param1] = this.funcTemplate;
  this[param2] = this.funcTemplate;
};

var dynamic = new myModule('what', 'ever');
```